# MacOSX. Application switch like in Windows 7 system

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

So when I worked on Windows 7 system there was a convenient taskbar feature: 
Applications pinned to taskbar (or not pinned) have their own switch shortcut depends on order e.g. win+1 = first application on taskbar, win+2 = second etc.. 
I had my browser pinned as an first application, IDE as second so I had the opportunity to switch to a particular application without unnecessary movements.
I'd like to find something like that for MacOSX system. It may be 3d party software.

Anyone has a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just switch between two open applications? or Be able to open the application with a shortcut??

To just switch, use Cmnd-Tab.

To open:

**Automator with Shortcut:**

If you have 10.6, This may be slower but you can use Automator, Very easy:

Step 1. Open Automator, 2. Choose "Services" 3. Set method of input to "no input" and keep other at "all applications" 3. Drag in "Launch Application" from side list. 4. Change the application to what you want 5. Save as something like Open[insert application]

Step 6.Open System Preferences 7. "Keyboard" section and "Keyboard Shortcuts" 8. "Services" 9.Find your new saved service 10. click far left to set you own shortcut!

Problems: Doesn't work if App doesn't support Services.

**Dock/Apple Menu:**
If it's speed in opening applications, you can use the Apple menu>Recent Items for a recent application. Or figure out how to get the Recent Applications stack on your Dock using Terminal.  This is what I use.

**3rd Party:**
Check out Quicksilver, you can set up shortcuts for the applications. Check out Alfred as well, allows shortcuts for apps.